# Passing integer by reference to a class in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a thread-class **Buffer** (own made class), and many derived classes such as **BufferTypeA**, **BufferTypeB**...

Since I have to synchronize them in a certain order, I'm giving any of them an integer which represents the order to run certain task. I also have to know inside each thread Buffer which one is next to run the task, so I'm passing every BufferType a reference to an integer which all of them must share and I didn't want to make it Global.

I got lost at any point and I don't see where.

First I create all the BufferTypes from a class where I also define that shared integer as:

```
int currentThreadOrder;
```

And when creating the BufferTypes:

```
int position = 0;
    if (NULL == bufferA) {
            bufferA = new BufferTypeA(&currentThreadOrder, ++position,
                        waitCondition);
        }
        if (NULL == bufferB) {
            bufferB = new BufferPos(&currentThreadOrder, ++position,
                        waitCondition);
        }
        if (NULL == bufferC) {
            bufferC = new BufferRtk(&currentThreadOrder, ++position,
                        waitCondition);
        }
```

Then, in BufferTypeA header:

```
class BufferTypeA: public Buffer {
public:
    BufferTypeA(int currentThreadOrder,
            int threadConnectionOrder = 0,
            QWaitCondition *waitCondition = NULL);
//..
}
```

And in cpp file:

```
BufferTypeA::BufferTypeA(int currentThreadOrder, int threadConnectionOrder, QWaitCondition *waitCondition):
        Buffer(currentThreadOrder, threadConnectionOrder, waitCondition) { }
```

Now I'll show Buffer header:

```
    class Buffer: public QThread {
    public:
        Buffer(int &currentThreadOrder,
                int threadConnectionOrder = 0,
                QWaitCondition *waitCondition = NULL);
    //...
protected:
    QWaitCondition *waitCondition;
    int threadConnectionOrder;
    int &currentThreadOrder; // Shared address
    }
```

And finally the cpp:

```
Buffer::Buffer(int &currentThreadOrder, int threadConnectionOrder, QWaitCondition *waitCondition) {

    this->threadConnectionOrder = threadConnectionOrder;
    this->waitCondition = waitCondition;
    this->currentThreadOrder = currentThreadOrder;
}
```

And the error I'm getting is *error: uninitialized reference member **Buffer::currentThreadOrder***.

I'm embarrased to ask, because it's going to be a simple problem with pointers and addresses, but I can't see where the problem is, so please help.

Comment: You need to use a member initializer to initialize your reference. By the time the body of the constructor executes, the members are initialized.

Comment: note how your ctor is (or is trying to) assigning to default initialized elements, use a ctor-initializer to initialize, everything else is not initialization.

Comment: @chris if I do so, then I won't be able to copy the reference I'm passing in order to use it in Buffer class members, am I right? How could I share that variable then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a class with a data-member that is a reference, the reference needs to be assigned a value in the constructor initializer list.

References have to be given a value when they are created, they are not pointers.  They have to start with a value and that value cannot be changed (while the contents that is pointed to by that value can be changed).

Essentially you can think of a reference as an alias for an existing variable.  **You can't give a friend a nickname if you don't have a friend :)**

**RESPONSE TO COMMENT:**

You don't "share a reference" between objects.  Each object will have its own reference to the same variable.  When you "pass by reference" you are telling the compiler that you want the variable in your function to actually be the variable in your outer scope, rather than creating a new variable by value.  This means that you only have one variable at one memory location. The reference is just memory in some other place that forwards you to that same memory location.

Think of this as call forwarding... I can have 15 phone numbers in 15 different countries. I can set them all up to forward calls to my cell in the US.  So, people are calling me no matter which number they call.

Each of your classes just has another reference to forward the "phone calls" or variable reads/writes to that same memory location.  So, you're not sharing a reference between classes, you're making sure that each class HAS a reference to the same underlying memory location.

Back to the metaphore, each class won't have the same phone, but each class' phone will forward to the same number (variable) none-the-less which lets them all set/get the same value in the end.

**RESPONSE II:**

Here's a simple example to get your head going, it's pretty easy to apply to your classes.  I didn't compile it but it should work minus a typo or two possibly.

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(int& shared) : m_shared(shared)
        {
            //No actions needed, initializer list initializes
            //reference above. We'll just increment the variable
            //so you can see it's shared in main.
            m_shared += 7;
        }

        void DoSomethingWithIt()
        {
            //Will always reflect value in main no matter which object
            //we are talking about.
            std::cout << m_shared << std::endl;
        }            

    private:

        //Reference variable, must be initialized in 
        //initializer list of constructor or you'll get the same
        //compiler error again.
        int& m_shared;
};

int main()
{
    int my_shared_integer = 0;

    //Create two A instances that share my_shared_integer.
    //Both A's will initialize their internal reference to
    //my_shared_integer as they will take it into their
    //constructors "by reference" (see & in constructor
    //signature) and save it in their initializer list.
    A myFirstA(my_shared_integer);
    A mySecondA(my_shared_integer);

    //Prints 14 as both A's incremented it by 7 in constructors.
    std::cout << my_shared_integer << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Then I can't copy the reference to use it in Buffer class methods. How could I share an integer between many classes without making it global then?

Comment: Added to answer above to help clarify.

Comment: @RomanRdgz:  Good question.  The answer is that an object like your integer need not be global to be shared.  Indeed, it probably should not be global.  Good programmers usually avoid global objects.  What is needed is that the object be defined in broad enough a scope that it lives until your several Buffers have done with it.

Comment: That's another good point actually.  While my answer discusses how to share it, you still need to make sure it lives long enough to be shared (especially if you're threading).  Ensure the original integer will outlive the objects referring to it or you get a dangling reference ==> Undefined Behavior.

Comment: I do understand that a reference is nothing but a memory address where a variable is, and I'm trying to access to that memory address from many classes. But The problem is that I know how to pass a reference, but not how to store it into the ctor to use later in class methods. That, and the BufferTypes ctor which make it even more confusing for me. How would I do that then?

Comment: Okay, I threw up a simple example to get you to understand the syntax better so you can apply it to your problem.

Comment: PS: I accidentally wrote "prints 7" instead of "prints 14" at first.  My bad, fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

you pass a pointer `int*` as 1st argument to `BufferTypeA`, which expects and `int`, while you said in your question you meant to use a `int&`. To do this, the ctor of `BufferTypeA` should take a `int&` and initialise it in an initialisation list (i.e. not within the `{ }` part of the ctor) like

```
class BufferType {
  int &Ref;
public:
  BufferTypeA(int& ref) : Ref(ref) { /* ... */ }
};
```

and in your construction of `BufferA` you must not pass an address, but the reference, i.e.

```
int counter;
Buffer = new BufferType(counter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want code like this:

```
Buffer::Buffer(
    int &currentThreadOrder0,
    const int threadConnectionOrder0,
    QWaitCondition *const waitCondition0
) :
  threadConnectionOrder(threadConnectionOrder0),
  waitCondition(waitCondition0),
  currentThreadOrder(currentThreadOrder0)
{}
```

The reason is related to the reason you cannot write

```
const double pi;
pi = 3.14;
```

but can write

```
const double pi = 3.14;
```

A reference is typically implemented as a constant pointer, to which one cannot assign an address after one has initialized the pointer.  Your version of the code *assigns,* as in the first `pi` example.  My version of the code *initializes,* as in the second `pi` example.

Comment: Ok, and I guess I could only initialize the first variable, and the other two as usual into the constructor without need to declare them as const, am I right? What about the BufferTypes? Is there any other error there, as @Walter solution says?

Comment: It appears the @Walter is right:  the `bufferA = new BufferTypeA(&currentThreadOrder, ++position, waitCondition);` should probably be `bufferA = new BufferTypeA(currentThreadOrder, ++position, &waitCondition);`  The various uses of the `&` ampersand operator are a common source of confusion among learning C++ programmers.  When declaring a symbol, the `&` means *reference to.*  In the other context, it means *address of.*

Comment: I have now compiled your code.  With the change I have suggested, and also with a few semicolons added after the definitions of types and with a little other syntactic cleanup, the modified code seems to work.